# LibGDX, intermittent lagging whilst moving an object

Tags: android, libgdx

I create little sprites of sheeps on the top of my screen, then they should go down and after crossing bottom line they disappear. Problem is that when they are going across the screen it is very noticable that sometimes they lag. For milliseconds but its possible to see it. It happens absolutely randomly. They change their position with Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

```
    public void update (float deltaTime) {
        updateMotionX(deltaTime);
        updateMotionY(deltaTime);

        // Move to new position
        position.x += velocity.x * deltaTime;
        position.y += velocity.y * deltaTime;
}
```

Here is the code of spawing them:

```
    private Sheep spawnSheep(){
    Sheep sheep = new Sheep();
    sheep.dimension.set(dimension);

    // select random cloud image
    sheep.setRegion(regSheeps.random());

    // position
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2();

    pos.x = -0.19f; // position after end of level
    pos.y = 5;

    sheep.position.set(pos);

    //speed
    Vector2 speed = new Vector2();
    speed.y = 3.5f;
    sheep.terminalVelocity.set(speed);
    speed.y *= -1;
    sheep.velocity.set(speed);
    return sheep;

}
```

Maybe somebody already had that problem, i have no idea why it happens,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lagging is most likely caused by garbage collection because you're continuously allocating memory within your game loop.

You want to avoid calling **new** whenever possible in the game loop, and if you do call new you want to reuse those objects whenever possible.

Look at pools in libgdx
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.html

If you're returning an object from a method, such as a Vector2, then create a static instance and reuse that object for return values. Be aware that this is not thread safe and calling the method again will overwrite the value from the first call.

If I was you I'd search for any instances of the word 'new' in your code, and make sure none of them are called frequently within the game loop. You also want to be aware of calling methods that will create instances of objects. Simple things like converting an integer to a string will waste memory, as well as more obvious things like creating a copy of an array.

You should find this useful for tracking memory allocation.
https://visualvm.java.net/